# Looking for a stereo USB camera driver for Jade

Tags: stereo, ros-jade, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm new to the ROS system, and my first project would be really simple:
I'd like to use the rtabmap for stereo SLAM.
My problem is, I was not able to find a camera driver node. For example: http://wiki.ros.org/uvc_camera would be great, but it is not released for Jade.

Does anyone have a working stereo camera driver node on Jade? Could you please tell me, how did you get it to work?

Thanks!
Adam

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220655/looking-for-a-stereo-usb-camera-driver-for-jade/) by [master_19](https://answers.ros.org/users/25040/master_19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [master_19](https://answers.ros.org/users/25040/master_19/) on 2015-11-16**:
Is there maybe an alternative way to get synchonized images from 2 USB cameras? Is it hard to write a stereo note using an existing simple USB camera driver?
I'm open to alternative solutions too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If uvc_camera suits your needs, you can download the source and build it yourself. The Indigo or Hydro versions are likely to build and run on Jade, too. At least, it's worth a try. If you don't know how to build a ROS package from source, comment on this answer and I'll provide links to some tutorials.

But, note that uvc_camera is no longer maintained, and its author, Ken Tossell, recommends using [libuvc_camera](http://wiki.ros.org/libuvc_camera), instead. There is no Jade release yet for that driver, either, so you'd still have to download and build that from source. But, at least it's actively maintained, so you could [open a github issue](https://github.com/ktossell/libuvc_ros/issues), requesting a Jade release.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [master_19](https://answers.ros.org/users/25040/master_19/) on 2015-11-16**:
I tried building the camera_uvc from source using this guide: https://defendtheplanet.net/2014/11/05/using-ros-indigo-webcam-by-the-uvc_camera-usb-video-class-package/ , the rosdep install part failed with "missing resource". But if I use catkin_make, it checks the dependencies, right?

**Comment by [master_19](https://answers.ros.org/users/25040/master_19/) on 2015-11-16**:
Catkin_make is successful: [100%] B[100%] Built target uvc_stereo_node. But after i try to launch it, it fails: "ERROR: cannot launch node of type [uvc_camera/camera_node]: can't locate node [camera_node] in package [uvc_camera]"
Is this an installation problem? Can you link me some tutorials?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-11-17**:
There are probably no tutorials, but if you edit your original question and copy the exact error text there (what you did and what it said), maybe we can figure out what went wrong.

**Comment by [kaygudo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25082/kaygudo/) on 2015-12-14**:
hey Joq can you tell me how to built ros package from source?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-12-15**:
Building from source tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_a_workspace .